# Why we don't use absolute value bars in the trigonometric substitution of indefinite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

For example let's say we have the following indefinite integral $$I=\int\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$We evaluate it by using trigonometric substitution $x=\sin\theta$:

$$I=\int\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}\cos\theta d\theta$$
Here we use $\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}=\cos\theta$ rather than $\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}=|\cos\theta|$. but why? isn't $\sqrt{u^2}=|u|$ ?

Comment: $\sqrt{u^2} = |u|$ is false for complex numbers.  Except in the most elementary courses, when doing analysis you will want to consider complex numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a function to $\mathbb{R}$, the domain is $[-1, 1]$. So, if $x= \sin(\theta)$, then $\theta  \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, and $\cos(\theta )$ is always positive on that interval.

Comment: Oh I got it. that's because by taking $x=\sin\theta$ we have $\theta=\sin^{-1}x$ and it accepts $\theta\in[-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2]$. Am I right?

Comment: @amirali Yes, that's a good way to think of it.