# Reasoning of step in trigonometric integration by substitution question

Tags: substitution, trigonometric-integrals

My textbook gives, as a worked example:

$(b)\ $ Use the substitution $\ x = \sec\theta\ $ to find $\ \int \left(x^2-1\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}}.$
$$$$
$$\ \int \left(x^2-1\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\ =\ldots=\ -\text{cosec }\theta\ +c.$$

$$x=\sec\theta\implies\cos\theta=\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\sin\theta = \sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}}\implies \text{cosec }\theta = \frac{1}{\sin\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}}$$

> Notice that, in choosing the substitution $\ x=\sec\theta,\ $ we can
> choose $\ \theta\ $ to be between $\ 0\ $ and $\ \pi.\ $ Then $\
>  \sin\theta\ $ is non-negative, so we can take the positive square root
> here.

I don't get the first step of the last line I've included, nor the explanation. Basically, I just don't buy this explanation as to why we can choose $\ \theta\ $ to be between $\ 0\ $ and $\ \pi\ $ rather than between $\ \pi\ $ and $\ 2\pi,\ $ or $\ \theta\ $ having some other input values of substitution. Can someone explain it to me in more detail please?

Comment: For $\theta\in[0,\pi]$, we have $0\le\sin\theta\le1$ so it can't be negative. hence $\sin\theta = -\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$ is not acceptable.

Comment: Yeah but for $\ \theta\in[\pi,2\pi],\ -1\leq\sin\theta\leq0,\ $ we get $\sin\theta = -\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}.\ $ which will give us a different answer. Why does it give us a different answer, and why do we favour using the interval  $\ \theta\in[0,\pi]\ $ as opposed to the interval $\ \theta\in[\pi,2\pi]?\ $

Comment: Hmm, I'm not %100 sure this is true: we can say when we substitute $x=\sec\theta$, we have $\theta=\sec^{-1}x$. and range of the function $\sec^{-1}x$  is $[0,\pi]-\{\frac{\pi}2\}$. hence theta lies on this interval.

Comment: I got this idea from the question I asked months ago here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098835/why-we-dont-use-absolute-value-bars-in-the-trigonometric-substitution-of-indefi

Comment: Ok well you may well be right, but the book I am using doesn't define or use $\ \text{arcsec}x\ $ so unfortunately your line of thought is probably not what the book intended one to look into. I think this is just a bad example from the book then, because it seems there is a lack of support in order to be able to understand this ?

Comment: I don't know. for the simple integral in the question I linked we don't define $\arcsin x$ too. it was the way I thought about this and David Lui approved my comment too :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be more accurate to say that we are making the substitution $\newcommand{\arcsec}{\operatorname{arcsec}}\theta=\arcsec x$. Then, by definition of $\arcsec$, $x=\sec\theta$ and $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$, where $\theta\neq\pi/2$. In this interval, $\sin\theta$ is nonnegative. We can rearrange the formula
$$
\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1
$$
to get
$$
|\sin\theta|=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta} \, .
$$
Since $\sin\theta$ is nonnegative in the specified interval, the formula simplifies to
$$
\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta} \, .
$$
**Remark**: when you make substitutions of the form $\theta=g(x)$ and rearrange to get $x=g^{-1}(\theta)$, it must be the case that $g$ is one-to-one (otherwise $g^{-1}$ wouldn't exist). For more details, see pages 370-371 of Michael Spivak's *Calculus*. Those who are fluent in making substitutions often don't bother writing the step $\theta=g(x)$. This is fine, so long as when they write $x=g^{-1}(\theta)$, they specify which values $\theta$ can take, so that it is clear that $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are one-to-one.

Comment: I am not familiar with, and the book I am using, doesn't define $\ \text{arcsec}\ x\ $.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: The function $\operatorname{arcsec}$ is the inverse of the function $f$ such that $$f(\theta)=\sec\theta \quad 0\leq\theta\leq\pi \, , \theta\neq\frac{\pi}{2} \, .$$However, that is not really the important point here. What's important is that when you make a substitution of the form $x=\phi(\theta)$ for some function $\phi$, it *must* be the case that $\phi$ is one-to-one on the interval being considered.

Comment: Ok. Your answer is relevant and it has led me to understand what the answer to my question is. But you haven't *fully* answered my question, which is why is the substitution  $\ x=\sec\theta,\ \theta\in [0,\pi]\ $ gives a different answer to the substitution $\ x=\sec\theta,\ \theta\in [\pi,2\pi]. $ But I am going to write an answer to this soon, because I think I have figured it out. Or maybe the question I am answering now in this comment is different from the question originally asked...

Comment: @AdamRubinson: I'm sorry, I didn't see that part of your question. I'll try to work out what happens when $\theta\in[\pi,2\pi]$ also.

Comment: I think we would need to show that:

$$\large{\left[ -\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}} \right]^{arcsec(b)}_{arcsec(a)} = \left[ \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}} \right]^{2\pi - arcsec(b)}_{2\pi -arcsec(a)}}$$

which I assume can be done, basically (even if it is messy). But I think I have discovered that without the $a$ and $b$, i.e. with the indefinite integration, you can get two different answers, although maybe they are the same answer and really they differ by a constant? But I don't think so...

Comment: @AdamRubinson: I think I've worked it out, although this solution might be unsatisfying to you as it uses the function $\newcommand{\arcsec}{\operatorname{arcsec}} \arcsec$. Anyway, if we make the substitution $x=\sec\theta$ with $\theta\in[0,\pi]$, then the answer to the indefinite integral is $-\csc\left(\arcsec x\right)+C$, whereas if we make the substitution $\theta\in[\pi,2\pi]$, then we get $-\csc\left(\pi-\arcsec x\right)+C$. Since $\csc(\arcsec x)=\csc(\pi-\arcsec x)$, these are the same thing.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: I'm sorry but I don't have time to post my working; if you're interested in how I arrived at this result then I can return to this problem in a few hours.

Comment: Yes, please do add these details to your answer whenever you have time as I am interested in how you got that.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: I think I've isolated the issue. My above comment is actually mistaken. What actually went wrong is that when we wrote $$I=\int (x^2-1)^{3/2} \, dx \, ,$$and made the substitution $x=\sec\theta$, we should have got $$I=\int \left(\tan^2\theta\right)^{-3/2}\sec\theta\tan\theta \, d\theta \, .$$Here, we are tempted to simplify $\left(\tan^2\theta\right)^{-3/2}$ to $(\tan\theta)^{-3}$, but this *only works if $\tan\theta$ is nonnegative*. So the problem cropped up much earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, with the substitution $x=\sec\theta$

$$\int \left(x^2-1\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\ dx= -\text{cosec }\theta$$
is true for the domain $\theta\in(0,\frac\pi2)\cup(\pi,\frac{3\pi}2)$, not for $\theta\in (0, \pi)$ as given in the book. Accordingly, the back substitution yields
$$ -\text{cosec }\theta=-\frac {\sec \theta}{\tan\theta}=-\frac x{\sqrt{x^2-1}}
$$